# How to wrap useQuery hook by promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, graphql

I have a graphql query and useQuery hook which return a lot of data. I start loading by click button and show when the data loading will be finished.
Is it possible to use Promise to wait loading data? Could you write it?

```
const GET_NAME= gql`
    query  {
        employee {
            id
            name
        }
    }
`;

...

function Form () {
...
    const { data } = useQuery(
        GET_NAME
    );

    const onClick = () => {

    ....
    return textInput.current!.value=data.employee.name;
```

Comment: As Joe Lloyd pointed out, the `useQuery` hook tells you when it's loading and when it's finished. You need to render a loading screen if `loading` is true, if there is an `error` show an error, else show the data.

Answer (score 2):

## Use the deconstructed values from getQuery

You dont need to add a promise, that is handled internally.

An example from the docs

```
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_DOGS);

  if (loading) return 'Loading...';  // whilst its loading this will retun
  if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`; // if there's an error this will return

  return <pre>{data}</pre> // if the other 2 are not true you must have data, this will return
```

as you can see the loading state is already inside the return. As well as an error. you can respond on these values while you wait for the data to return.

Comment: Thank you for response, could you explain how it works inside? Is it based on Promise or other async tools?

Comment: @Michael it's probably callback-based